# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds with dead lock

Tags: php

it seem like i get stocked in loop ,i didn't know why this is my code-

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gdwal");
$sub = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *,priority FROM subjects,teacher WHERE teach =techID  ");
$stack = array();
$num = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(capacity)'h' FROM rooms  ");
$table[][] = array();
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($num);
$table[0][0] = 0;




    if ($db) {
        echo 'connected';
    }


    /* function seet()
      {
      global $db;
      $a=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from options  ");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) {$z=$row['choices'];
      echo($z);
      $e=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from timeslot where sname=$z  ");
      $y=mysqli_fetch_array($e);
      $x=$y['sindex'];
      echo"//////$x/////+";
      $b=mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE options SET `choices`=$x WHERE choices=$z  ");
      if($db->query($b)===true)
      {
      echo "lk";
      }
      }
      }
      seet(); */
    for ($u = 0; $u <= 70; $u++) {
        for ($g = 0; $g < 10; $g++) {
            $table[$u][$g] = 0;
        }
    }
    choose();

    function choose() {
        $sum = 0;
        $sums = 0;
        $best = array();
        $prev = 0;
        $best[0] = 0;
        $best[1] = 0;
        $best[2] = 100;
        $best[3] = 0;
        $best[4] = 0;
        global $sub;
        global $table;
        global $stack;
        global $db;
        $ee = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT  a.cid,c.NOstd,t.priority,c.hours,a.choices ,class,c.teacher_id FROM options a LEFT JOIN subjects c ON c.subject_id = a.cid LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id = c.teacher_id  ");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ee)) {
            if (!in_array($row['cid'], $stack)) {
                $r = $row['cid'];
                echo "$r-----";
                $new = $r;
                if ($prev===$new) {

                } else {
                    $sum = 0;
                    $prev =$new;
                }




                $z = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ind FROM rooms where capacity>='$r'");

                while ($j = mysqli_fetch_array($z)) {
                    $hh = $row['choices'];
                    $uu = $j['ind'];

                    if ($table[$hh][$uu] == 0) {
                        $sum++;
                    }
                }

                if ($sum == 0) {

                    break;
                }
                $sums = $sum;
                if ($best[2] == $sum && $best[3] < $row['priority']) {
                        echo $row['cid'];
                        echo '09090909090909';
                    $best[0] = $row['cid'];
                    $best[1] = $row['NOstd'];
                    $best[2] = $sums;
                    $best[3] = $row['priority'];
                    $best[4] = $row['teacher_id'];
                    $best[5] = $row['hours'];
                    $best[6] = $row['class'];
                } else {
                    if ($best[2] > $sum) {


                        $best[0] = $row['cid'];
                        $best[1] = $row['NOstd'];
                        $best[2] = $sums;
                        $best[3] = $row['priority'];
                        $best[4] = $row['teacher_id'];
                        $best[5] = $row['hours'];
                        $best[6] = $row['class'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        back($best);
    }

    function back($courses) {

        global $stack;
        global $db;
        global $table;
        $y =$courses[0];

        $i = 0;
        global$x;
        $numsub = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cid)'jj'  FROM options ");
        $nn = mysqli_fetch_array($numsub);


        $t = 0;
        echo "XXX";
        echo "//$y//";
        echo "SELECT * FROM options WHERE cid='$y'";
        echo "XXX";
        $slot = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM options WHERE cid='$y'");

        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($slot)) {
            $rom = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms where capacity>='$courses[1]'");
            $j = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms where capacity>='$courses[1]'");
            while ($D = mysqli_fetch_array($rom)) {
                if ($courses[5] == 3) {
                    echo "22";
                    if ($table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']] != 0 && $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$D['ind']] != 0) {
                        $z = $table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']];
                        $ff = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT teacher FROM subjects where course_id=$z ");
                        $selec = mysqli_fetch_array($ff);
                        $b = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`class`)'kk'FROM `subjects` WHERE `class` IN(SELECT `class` FROM subjects WHERE `course_id`=$z ) AND( course_id =$y OR`ssubject`=$y");
                        $count = mysqli_fetch_array($b);
                        if ($count['kk'] != 0 || $selec['teacher'] == $courses[4]) {
                            $t++;
                        }
                    }
                } else
                if ($table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']] != 0) {
                    $z = $table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']];
                    $ff = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT teacher FROM subjects where course_id=$z ");
                    $selec = mysqli_fetch_array($ff);
                    $b = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`class`)'kk'FROM `subjects` WHERE `class` IN(SELECT `class` FROM subjects WHERE `course_id`=$z ) AND( course_id =$y OR`ssubject`=$y");
                    $count = mysqli_fetch_array($b);
                    if ($count['kk'] != 0 || $selec['teacher'] == $courses[4]) {
                        $t++;
                        if ($t != 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    echo "1";
                }



                if ($t != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while ($colmn = mysqli_fetch_array($j)) {



                if ($courses[5] == 3) {
                    echo "uuuuuu";
                    $w = $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']];
                    $y = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT hours FROM subjects where course_id='$w' ");
                    $op = mysqli_fetch_array($y);
                    if ($op['hours'] == 3) {

                        $i = $table[($rows['choices'] - 1)][$colmn['ind']];
                        $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT hours ,course_id , FROM subjects WHERE course_id=$i");
                        $opi = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
                        if ($opi['hours'] == 3 && $opi['course_id'] == $w) {
                            array_push($stack, $courses[0]);
                            $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];

                            if (count($stack) == $nn['jj']) {
                                database($table);
                                break;
                            }
                            choose();

                            $table[($rows['choices']) + 1][$colmn['ind']] = 0;

                            array_pop($stack);
                        } 
                    } elseif ($table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] == 0) {

                        array_push($stack, $courses[0]);

                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];
                        $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];

                        if (count($stack) == $nn['jj']) {

                            database($table);
                            break;
                        }
                        choose();
                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = 0;
                        $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$colmn['ind']] = 0;

                        array_pop($stack);
                    }

                    //end of t 
                }//end of courses 3
                else {
                    if ($t == 0 && $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] == 0) {
                        array_push($stack, $courses[0]);
                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];



                        if (count($stack) == $nn['jj']) {

                            database($table);
                            break;
                        }
                        choose();


                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = 0;


                        array_pop($stack);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    global $sub;

    function database($tab) {   // print_r($tab);
        global $db;
        $g = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM timeslot");
        $r = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms");
        while ($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($g)) {
            while ($co = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {



                if ($tab[$ro['sindex']][$co['ind']] === 0) {

                } else {
                    echo 'iam in 2';
                    $x = $tab[$ro['sindex']][$co['ind']];
                    $u = mysqli_query($db, "select subject_id,hours,teacher_id,class from subjects WHERE subject_id='$x'");
                    $cor = mysqli_fetch_array($u);
                    $na = $cor['subject_id'];
                    $ho = $cor['hours'];
                    $tea = $cor['teacher_id'];
                    $clas = $cor['class'];
                    $tim = $ro['sindex'];
                    $km = $co['ind'];
                    $rmm = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT name FROM rooms where ind=$km");
                    $rom = mysqli_fetch_array($rmm);
                    $romm = $rom['name'];
                    $n = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO ttable(name, teacher,class, timeslot, room, hours) VALUES ($na,$tea,$clas,$tim,$romm,$ho)");
                    $t = "INSERT INTO ttable(name, teacher, timeslot, room, hours) VALUES ('$na','$tea','$tim','$romm','$ho')";
                    echo "uuututyttuy";
                    if ($db->query($t) === true) {
                        echo "lklklklklklklklkl";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you done already to try and solve the problem? Consider making a separate version of the code which is simplified and recreates the problem. It will make it easier for you to get help.

Comment: "I have a problem here is my code" ? - Please refer to [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236), and edit your question to be on-topic for StackOverflow. For help with this, you can refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). An important addition to your question is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your "back" function calls "choose" function.
And your "choose" function calls your "back" function.
The loop is complete.

I have marked it with `////////` to make it easy to find.
Edit I see now that there is several places in back you call choose. I have only marked one.
It's not to hard to find it with search function of any developer app.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gdwal");
$sub = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *,priority FROM subjects,teacher WHERE teach =techID  ");
$stack = array();
$num = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(capacity)'h' FROM rooms  ");
$table[][] = array();
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($num);
$table[0][0] = 0;




    if ($db) {
        echo 'connected';
    }


    /* function seet()
      {
      global $db;
      $a=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from options  ");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) {$z=$row['choices'];
      echo($z);
      $e=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from timeslot where sname=$z  ");
      $y=mysqli_fetch_array($e);
      $x=$y['sindex'];
      echo"//////$x/////+";
      $b=mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE options SET `choices`=$x WHERE choices=$z  ");
      if($db->query($b)===true)
      {
      echo "lk";
      }
      }
      }
      seet(); */
    for ($u = 0; $u <= 70; $u++) {
        for ($g = 0; $g < 10; $g++) {
            $table[$u][$g] = 0;
        }
    }
    choose();

    function choose() {
        $sum = 0;
        $sums = 0;
        $best = array();
        $prev = 0;
        $best[0] = 0;
        $best[1] = 0;
        $best[2] = 100;
        $best[3] = 0;
        $best[4] = 0;
        global $sub;
        global $table;
        global $stack;
        global $db;
        $ee = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT  a.cid,c.NOstd,t.priority,c.hours,a.choices ,class,c.teacher_id FROM options a LEFT JOIN subjects c ON c.subject_id = a.cid LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id = c.teacher_id  ");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ee)) {
            if (!in_array($row['cid'], $stack)) {
                $r = $row['cid'];
                echo "$r-----";
                $new = $r;
                if ($prev===$new) {

                } else {
                    $sum = 0;
                    $prev =$new;
                }




                $z = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ind FROM rooms where capacity>='$r'");

                while ($j = mysqli_fetch_array($z)) {
                    $hh = $row['choices'];
                    $uu = $j['ind'];

                    if ($table[$hh][$uu] == 0) {
                        $sum++;
                    }
                }

                if ($sum == 0) {

                    break;
                }
                $sums = $sum;
                if ($best[2] == $sum && $best[3] < $row['priority']) {
                        echo $row['cid'];
                        echo '09090909090909';
                    $best[0] = $row['cid'];
                    $best[1] = $row['NOstd'];
                    $best[2] = $sums;
                    $best[3] = $row['priority'];
                    $best[4] = $row['teacher_id'];
                    $best[5] = $row['hours'];
                    $best[6] = $row['class'];
                } else {
                    if ($best[2] > $sum) {


                        $best[0] = $row['cid'];
                        $best[1] = $row['NOstd'];
                        $best[2] = $sums;
                        $best[3] = $row['priority'];
                        $best[4] = $row['teacher_id'];
                        $best[5] = $row['hours'];
                        $best[6] = $row['class'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
/////////////////
/////////////////
/////////////////
        back($best);
    }

    function back($courses) {

        global $stack;
        global $db;
        global $table;
        $y =$courses[0];

        $i = 0;
        global$x;
        $numsub = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cid)'jj'  FROM options ");
        $nn = mysqli_fetch_array($numsub);


        $t = 0;
        echo "XXX";
        echo "//$y//";
        echo "SELECT * FROM options WHERE cid='$y'";
        echo "XXX";
        $slot = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM options WHERE cid='$y'");

        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($slot)) {
            $rom = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms where capacity>='$courses[1]'");
            $j = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms where capacity>='$courses[1]'");
            while ($D = mysqli_fetch_array($rom)) {
                if ($courses[5] == 3) {
                    echo "22";
                    if ($table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']] != 0 && $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$D['ind']] != 0) {
                        $z = $table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']];
                        $ff = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT teacher FROM subjects where course_id=$z ");
                        $selec = mysqli_fetch_array($ff);
                        $b = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`class`)'kk'FROM `subjects` WHERE `class` IN(SELECT `class` FROM subjects WHERE `course_id`=$z ) AND( course_id =$y OR`ssubject`=$y");
                        $count = mysqli_fetch_array($b);
                        if ($count['kk'] != 0 || $selec['teacher'] == $courses[4]) {
                            $t++;
                        }
                    }
                } else
                if ($table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']] != 0) {
                    $z = $table[$rows['choices']][$D['ind']];
                    $ff = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT teacher FROM subjects where course_id=$z ");
                    $selec = mysqli_fetch_array($ff);
                    $b = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`class`)'kk'FROM `subjects` WHERE `class` IN(SELECT `class` FROM subjects WHERE `course_id`=$z ) AND( course_id =$y OR`ssubject`=$y");
                    $count = mysqli_fetch_array($b);
                    if ($count['kk'] != 0 || $selec['teacher'] == $courses[4]) {
                        $t++;
                        if ($t != 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    echo "1";
                }



                if ($t != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while ($colmn = mysqli_fetch_array($j)) {



                if ($courses[5] == 3) {
                    echo "uuuuuu";
                    $w = $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']];
                    $y = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT hours FROM subjects where course_id='$w' ");
                    $op = mysqli_fetch_array($y);
                    if ($op['hours'] == 3) {

                        $i = $table[($rows['choices'] - 1)][$colmn['ind']];
                        $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT hours ,course_id , FROM subjects WHERE course_id=$i");
                        $opi = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
                        if ($opi['hours'] == 3 && $opi['course_id'] == $w) {
                            array_push($stack, $courses[0]);
                            $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];

                            if (count($stack) == $nn['jj']) {
                                database($table);
                                break;
                            }
                            choose();

                            $table[($rows['choices']) + 1][$colmn['ind']] = 0;

                            array_pop($stack);
                        } 
                    } elseif ($table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] == 0) {

                        array_push($stack, $courses[0]);

                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];
                        $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];

                        if (count($stack) == $nn['jj']) {

                            database($table);
                            break;
                        }
                        choose();
                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = 0;
                        $table[($rows['choices'] + 1)][$colmn['ind']] = 0;

                        array_pop($stack);
                    }

                    //end of t 
                }//end of courses 3
                else {
                    if ($t == 0 && $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] == 0) {
                        array_push($stack, $courses[0]);
                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = $courses[0];



                        if (count($stack) == $nn['jj']) {

                            database($table);
                            break;
                        }
///////////////////////
///////////////////////
///////////////////////
                        choose();


                        $table[$rows['choices']][$colmn['ind']] = 0;


                        array_pop($stack);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    global $sub;

    function database($tab) {   // print_r($tab);
        global $db;
        $g = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM timeslot");
        $r = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms");
        while ($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($g)) {
            while ($co = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {



                if ($tab[$ro['sindex']][$co['ind']] === 0) {

                } else {
                    echo 'iam in 2';
                    $x = $tab[$ro['sindex']][$co['ind']];
                    $u = mysqli_query($db, "select subject_id,hours,teacher_id,class from subjects WHERE subject_id='$x'");
                    $cor = mysqli_fetch_array($u);
                    $na = $cor['subject_id'];
                    $ho = $cor['hours'];
                    $tea = $cor['teacher_id'];
                    $clas = $cor['class'];
                    $tim = $ro['sindex'];
                    $km = $co['ind'];
                    $rmm = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT name FROM rooms where ind=$km");
                    $rom = mysqli_fetch_array($rmm);
                    $romm = $rom['name'];
                    $n = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO ttable(name, teacher,class, timeslot, room, hours) VALUES ($na,$tea,$clas,$tim,$romm,$ho)");
                    $t = "INSERT INTO ttable(name, teacher, timeslot, room, hours) VALUES ('$na','$tea','$tim','$romm','$ho')";
                    echo "uuututyttuy";
                    if ($db->query($t) === true) {
                        echo "lklklklklklklklkl";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```